# Facebook FB.ui "share" dialog - post to feed, but not share a link?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk, share, feed

I'm trying to post message into user's feed. But there is no more link to the FB.ui "feed" dialog.
If you use [direct link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.0) - you'll see that this feature is marked as "Legacy Feed Dialogs" (but still work).

> We have replaced the Feed/Share dialogs with a new, [modern Share
>   Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) that can perform all of the same functions as these older
>   dialogs, but additionally can publish Open Graph actions without any
>   Facebook Login required. Read our guide to this newer dialog.

They say "can perform all of the same functions" but I can see nothing about a simple post to feed, not a link sharing. There are no such fields as picture, description, picture etc...
Of course usually you can share a link to a page with open graph tags.. But I can't - I need to make a post from facebook app to share a picture at the user's wall.
How can I do this? Should I continue to use "feed" dialog? :)
Thank!